# Metric around infinitely long rod

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

What is the metric tensor describing spacetime around an infinitely long rod?

Comment: Is this a 1-dimensional singularity, or a rod of finite mass density and finite thickness?

Comment: If it matters then finite density and thickness. But I want to know the metric outside the rod.